# problem in the demo of an equinumerosity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of a theorem about equinumerosity of 2 sets, but I am facing to a problem.  Here is the summary of my issue:

> Let $h$ be a bijective function from $E$ to $h(E)$ with the
>   particularity that $h(E)\subset E$, $h^0(E)=E$,
>
> Let $h^{n+1}(E) = h(h^n(E))$ be the sequence of sets given by the
>   image of $E$ by $h$ with the particularity that $h^{n+1}(E)\subset h^n(E)$.
>
> Finally, let $(A_n)$ be a sequence defined by $A_0=E \setminus h(E)$,
>   $A_{n+1}=h(A_n)=h^n(E)\setminus h^{n+1}(E)$.

The proof continues, but I don't understand why $h(A_n)=h^n(E)\setminus h^{n+1}(E)$.  To reduce the problem, and because a recurrence is possible, let's consider only the first iteration of the equality:
$$
h(E\setminus h(E))=h(E)\setminus h^2(E)
$$

Alone, I would not have produced this equality. Why is it true? What are the requirements concerning h?

thank you,

lowley

Comment: h is a bijection between E and h(E)

Comment: So they are equipotent but they can be infinite

Comment: If it is not clear to you, I can copy the theorem and the beginning of the demonstration,but it will require some time

Comment: @Morgan: I think the OP means that we have an injection $h:E\to E,$ so that $h$ is a bijection from $E$ to $h(E).$

Comment: I changed $E\backslash h(E)$ to $E\setminus h(E).$ The former does not have proper spacing. \backslash is not intended as a binary operation symbol; \setminus is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we think about the set $E \setminus h(E)$, this is the set $\{ x : x \in E \mbox{ and } x \not\in h(E) \}$.  So if we apply $h$ to this set, we see that for such an $x$, $h(x) \in h(E)$ (obviously), but we cannot have $h(x) \in h^{2}(x)$ (since $x$ was not in $h(E)$). This uses the fact that $h$ is one-to-one; by definition, an element $y$ is in $h^{2}(E)$ if there exists some $x$ in $h(E)$ with $h(x) = y$; since $h$ is one-to-one, you are guaranteed that there is not an $x^{\prime} \neq x$ (and so possibly not in $h(E)$) that also has $h(x^{\prime}) = y \in h^{2}(E)$.

This shows that $h(E \setminus h(E)) \subset h(E) \setminus h^{2}(E)$.  Now you just need to show the reverse inclusion to finish the proof.

Comment: well, it seems simple : let's $x\in h(E)\backslash h^2(E)$, there is an y such as $x=h(y)$ and y verifies there is no z such as $y=h(z)$, so it remains to verify that $y\in E\backslash h(E)$; $x\in h(E)$ so, given that h is a bijection, we know that y belongs to E, and $y\ne h(z) \Rightarrow y\not\in h(E)$. Is this correct?